# How to provide paginated results from google cloud bigquery using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-bigquery

I am using Ruby on Rails application and want to fetch the datasets, tables in a paginated manner.

Using `gem 'google-cloud-bigquery'` for my application.

Here is code for creating Bigquery client

```
 Google::Cloud::Bigquery.configure do |config|
      config.project_id  = project_id
      config.credentials = credentials
    end

 @bigquery = Google::Cloud::Bigquery.new
```

Fetching datasets

```
datasets = @bigquery.datasets
```

Above line fetches only first 50 records. But I want use the pagination for the dataset list. How can I achieve it using this gem in Ruby on Rails?

Example:

```
Total datasets = 170
Limit per page = 30
Total no of pages = 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke the `#next` method on it. From the [docs itself](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/blob/a5b2c0d0a2c2ab3c5cd6d7ef96b984b03a3d33f2/google-cloud-bigquery/lib/google/cloud/bigquery/dataset/list.rb#L58) the code snippet will look something like this

```rb
datasets = @bigquery.datasets
if datasets.next? # Checks if there are more datasets
    next_datasets = datasets.next # gets the next dataset list.
end
```

It all is controlled by the `token` returned in the last response which is the location of the next page. Regarding the page size itself, there seems to be a max variable if you look inside the next method which I am not sure where it is being set from initially.